# Cadvisor not launching at the correct port

Tags: linux, systemd, daemon

I am trying to monitor the metrics of my computer using grafana, prometheus and cadvisor.
I tried to run cadvisor as follows:

```
cadvisor -port=9091
```

It works really well. However I want it to launch on its own without my intervention on boot so I thought I would use `systemd`.

I tried launching cadvisor as a service using [Unit configration](https://www.mankier.com/5/systemd.service)
files.
Here is the contents of `/etc/systemd/system/cadvisor.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=cadvisor
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
User=cadvisor
Group=cadvisor
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/cadvisor -port=9101

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Afterwards, I did:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable cadvisor
systemctl status cadvisor
# this shows:
   Main PID: 1730601 (cadvisor)
      Tasks: 46 (limit: 76949)
     Memory: 64.0M
     CGroup: /system.slice/cadvisor.service
             └─1730601 /usr/bin/cadvisor --docker=unix:///var/run/docker.sock --port=4194 --storage_driver= --storage_driver_host=localhost:8086 --storage_driver_password=root --storage_driver_secure=false --st>
```

The problem is that cadvisor is running on the port **4194** instead of **9091**.
Why is it running on the wrong port ?
And how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed via apt-get then the `cadvisor` config file will be at `/etc/default/cadvisor`.

Change the `CADVISOR_PORT` field and restart the service.